# I want to disable resizing of screen during the double click on the title bar

Tags: c#

I want to disable the resizing of the form in my application.I have disabled maximize and minimize buttons but while double clicking on the title bar the form is resized.I have kept maximized is true. can any one tell me how to disable the resizing.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to disable the resizing of the form when the user double click on the title bar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set the MaximumSize attribute of your form.

Comment: This will works only for same sized screen. but i want my application form should be in maximized mode and it should not be resized while double clicking on the title bar. So it will not work for different size screen my monitor.

Answer (score 2):

Set FormBorderStyle to FixedSingle

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FixedSingle;
```

Comment: It doesnt prevent maximizing on double click on title bar. Setting any border style doesn`t work. (.Net Framework 4-4.8 at least)

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it by creating doubleClick event handler for your form:

> ```
>     private void yourForm_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         return;
>     }
> ```